# dlopen symbol not found in flat namespace '_ffi_prep_closure'

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error with the traceback. I have tried install reinstalling `cryptography`. Went through this as well `https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/946` as well with no solution and a few other solution but nothing worked.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_ffi_prep_closure'
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at /Users/runner/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pyo3-0.18.3/src/err/mod.rs:790:5:
Python API call failed
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/rj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/api/accounts/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .users.models import (
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/api/accounts/users/models.py", line 23, in <module>
    from libs.clients import paytm_client, redis_consumer_client, ola_client, amazonpay_client
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/api/libs/clients/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from py_commons.clients.mongo import MongoClient
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py_commons/clients/mongo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pymongo
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/__init__.py", line 93, in <module>
    from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 62, in <module>
    from pymongo import (
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 34, in <module>
    from pymongo.client_options import _parse_ssl_options
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/client_options.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pymongo.pool import PoolOptions
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 79, in <module>
    from pymongo.network import command, receive_message
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pymongo import _csot, helpers, message, ssl_support
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/ssl_support.py", line 25, in <module>
    import pymongo.pyopenssl_context as _ssl
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/pyopenssl_context.py", line 28, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509 import load_der_x509_certificate as _load_der_x509_certificate
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509 import certificate_transparency
  File "/Users/rj/vogo/consumer-api/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/x509/certificate_transparency.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import x509 as rust_x509
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Python API call failed
```